# system admin problem simulator (like GNS3 for networking)

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, administration

some month ago I read an article with advices for linux system administrators candidate and it referred to some kind of virtual machine with common problems for system admin to solve.
The point is that I'm not able to find it again and I don't remember the name. Is there someone who ever heard about it? Or something similar? 
Thanks